# Cloudformation : access other resources in the stack folder, where is the folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Suppose I have a cloudformation template with nested stacks.

I check them all out of git, create an S3 bucket and folder and point Cloudformation at the master template file.

I want it to import the nested stacks (and some other resources) from the "current" bucket/folder.

Does the stack have a property : where it's "source" comes from?

Or do I need to request the s3 URL from the user when they create the stack? So first you choose your file in S3, then you have to copy the URL press next and paste the URL. Seems like there must be a cleaner solution!

(I don't want to reference a central S3 bucket with the nested stacks available for public access, for policy reasons AND I expect the stack to be modified a little bit each time it's used, it isn't always exactly the same files that are being nested.)

Answer (score 2):

For your solution, what you can do is simply using that S3 URL that passed to the nested stack using the "Parameter" property. Please check it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-parameters
"The set of parameters passed to AWS CloudFormation when this nested stack is created."

And other notes:

1. In the S3 URL that you provided, you just mapped to a specific region endpoint. The other URL is valid as well, there are more options to provide S3 URLs. That based on the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#create-bucket-intro
2. No, the stack is not aware of his source and you can see all the options that related to stack here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#aws-resource-cloudformation-stack-syntax

Answer (score 0):

In the "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack" resource, you should use the "TemplateURL" property.

For Example:

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
  "Properties" : {
    "NotificationARNs" : [ String, ... ],
    "Parameters" : { AWS CloudFormation Stack Parameters },
    "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ... ],
    "TemplateURL" : String,
    "TimeoutInMinutes" : Integer
  }
}
```

"TemplateURL" - 
The URL of a template that specifies the stack that you want to create as a resource. Template files can use any extension, such as .json, .yaml, .template, or .txt. The template must be stored on an Amazon S3 bucket, so the URL must have the form: https://s3.amazonaws.com/.../TemplateName.extension

For more details:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-templateurl

Please let me know if more help is needed.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what is the URL for a file in the same bucket as the master template?
Also, I want to generate a lambda function from a .zip file stored in the same bucket. Which just needs a bucket name. 
And what you've pasted above is wrong. There is no need to be https://s3.amazonaws.com, my currently working example  :
TemplateURL: !Sub https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/${S3Bucket}/createPasswordLambda.yml
The URL is not s3.amazonaws.com....
My question is : Does the stack have a property : where it's "source" comes from?